# Repetitive map in Basemap

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

How I can do an repetitive on longitude map in Basemap for a satellite track?

[Like this map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoGbL.png)

To have an continuously satellite track, I tried whit diferents `llcrnrlon` and `urcrnrlon`. In the case for a set `llcrnrlon=-180` and `urcrnrlon` with a value major of `180` (to intent repeat some meridians), basemap don't generate the map

[This is the current map of the satellite track](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1BdO.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a minimum value of `-360` to `llcrnrlon` and a maximum value of `720` to `urcrnrlon` (with a larger extent `Basemap` will complain). With this kind of setting, some functions of `Basemap` produce repeating images. It's maybe best to just show an example:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits import basemap
import numpy as np
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,6))

lonmin = -360
lonmax = 720
latmin = -90
latmax = 90

##setting up the map
bmp = basemap.Basemap(
    ax=ax,
    llcrnrlat=latmin, llcrnrlon=lonmin,
    urcrnrlat=latmax, urcrnrlon=lonmax,
    )
bmp.drawcoastlines()
bmp.drawcountries()
bmp.drawmapboundary(fill_color='cyan')
bmp.fillcontinents(color='coral')
##bmp.arcgisimage() <-- does not work
##bmp.bluemarble() <-- works to some extent

##drawing a fake track
lons = np.linspace(lonmin, lonmax, 200)
rads = lons/150*np.pi
lats = np.sin(rads)*0.95*latmax
bmp.plot(lons,lats, 'r--', lw=5)
plt.show()
```

The resulting image looks like this:

[image: result of the above code]

As you can see, the last part (to the right) of the map is not drawn anymore, so it's maybe best to constrain yourself to a maximum value of `540` for `urcrnrlon`. I also two background image functions. `arcgisimage()` throws and error that it cannot handle maps which cross the day boundary, but `bluemarble()` works, even though only on a smaller area. If you want the map to repeat even more often, I think you will have to `stitch` together multiple axes and then split your data into parts, which you then plot on the respective maps.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful your answer. To use `blue marble()` or similars, I tried with this solution [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38243506/python-basemap-error-using-shadedrelief-bluemarble-or-etopo-false-longitude-f), but in an extreme of the plot (less to -180 or max of 180 longitude) the background is blur.

Comment: @CarlosMarioCuervoLópez For me the `bluemarble()` output looks good between `-180` and `540`. Why it behaves this way is beyond me.